# Running multiple tasks with one PHP file

Tags: php, mysqli, cron, minecraft

I am trying to make a weekly raffle system. Here is what I would like it to do. Every week a cron job will run "cron.php", which is going to randomly select a user from a database.

Once it does that it will give them an item on the Minecraft server using JSONAPI. After that it will post a news status on the main website saying 'gratz' or whatever. I can do all these things on there own but I'm confused on how I would do this all with one PHP file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
//Selects a random entry from the database and gives them something in game and also says Congradulations on the website as a news post under the name "TCCraft". 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "uname", "pass", "db with usernames in it"); 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
} 

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, name FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")) { //selects random user from the database.
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row['name']; //$name stands for the randomly selected user.
    //now its time to run the code to give the player the reward. We are using JSONAPI http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/jsonapi/
    require('JSONAPI.php');
        $obj = new JSONAPI('IP', 20059, 'unam', 'pass', 535153);
        $result = $obj->call("givePlayerItem", array("{$name}, 264, 24"));
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //connect to news db
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "uname", "pass", "db for all the news posts");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    $sql="INSERT INTO posts (title, user, body, date) VALUES ('Raffle Winner!','TCCraft','<p>Congradulations to {$name} for winning our weekly raffle!</p><p>If you would like to enter the raffle click <a href='http://tccraft.net/enter.php'>here</a></p>','$time')";
    echo "should be added";
}
?>
```

I tested this code out and got no errors, but it also didn't work lol The real problem is just adding the news post to the news database.

Comment: Didn't work in what way? You don't seem to be checkinf for errors from the JSONAPI call.

Comment: The JSONAPI isnt the problem. The problem is adding the news to the database. I should state that I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

First, you just assign the `INSERT` query string to a variable. You need to do:

```
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Second, the are quoting problems in the query. You need to escape the quotes around the `href` tag, or they'll be interpreted as delimiting the `VALUES` string.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO posts (title, user, body, date) VALUES ('Raffle Winner!','TCCraft','<p>Congradulations to {$name} for winning our weekly raffle!</p><p>If you would like to enter the raffle click <a href=\\'http://tccraft.net/enter.php\\'>here</a></p>','$time')";
```

Comment: You should add error checking code. The missing query call was obvious, but I could easily have missed the quoting problem. You need to check for errors so that the syntax error will be reported.

Answer (score 0):

You just assign a variable contains the sql sentence, but didn't run it ...
Add `$res = mysqli_query($sql);` after `$sql="INSERT INTO ...";`